# is there an open equivalent to OLE

Tags: ole, odf

Is there any kind of open equivalent to OLE, for use with ODF? Or equivalent functionality in some other format (e.g., OLE for DocBook XML) - complete with open-source protocol infrastructure?

Comment: I attempted to do something with OpenOffice on 2010. At that time, it had support for OLE.